# Connect anchor points of circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am very new to Illustrator and I need to fill a shape which is enclosed by two half circles with white. However, the circles are not connected, which means that trying to fill the inside fills the whole artwork.

[image]

In the image, you can see where I want to connect the two half circles, to be able to fill only the inside (everything left to that).

**How can I connect the two end points with a round path?** Using the Pen tool, I am only able to create straight paths, and I haven't managed to simply continue the circles round path. If you have an idea on how I can fill the inside in a different way, I am also very open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a much easier way to create something like that. It involves the use of a clipping mask.

1. Create some shapes with the required colours. Something like this.

[image]

2. Select all, and group all the shapes
3. Draw a circle over the top - this will be used as a clipping mask
4. With the Selection tool <kbd>V</kbd> hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on both the circle and the group to select them both
5. Click *Object > Clipping Mask > Make*

[image]

More info on using clipping masks is available on the [Adobe help website](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Say this is your (I have only re-traced your given sample but not exact shapes)[image]

[image]
just extend more your line overlaping the orange and blue or see the path of the original circle which is divided into colors

[image]

select the no fill & no stroke paths then use shape builder tool

[image]

use temporary color first just to see in the layer menu then recolor later